# Edit a db item through object name in ERB | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page in my rails app that renders products from the database that is not the products index page. I was wondering about the following:

> How can I edit an item through the object from a `do` statement?

**Bonus:** Is it possible to code the following statement to allow for `@pack` instead of through the object's `track` object?

My view:

```
<% @packs['track-indie']&.each do |track| %>
  <div class="wellington top-drop">
    <div>
      <h3 class="soundtrack-heading align-left pack-name"><%= track.title %></h3>
      <button class="btn btn-price align-right hidden-xs btn-bump" type="button">$<%= track.price %></button>
      <button class="btn btn-success align-right btn-bump" id="btn-buy" type="button">Buy!</button>
      <% if current_user.present? && current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", track, class: "btn btn-warning align-right btn-bump" %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", track,
                      method: :delete,
                      data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this pack?"},
                      class: "btn btn-danger align-right" %>
      <% end %>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe width="100%" height="110" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="<%= track.audio_embed %>"></iframe>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I press the edit button it says that there is no product with that name. I've even tried to use `method: :edit` but that doesn't seem to work either.

The error I get when I press the edit button when using `:update` or `:edit` is a routing error. It states: `No route matches [POST] "/products/the-hunt"` yet I'm able to navigate there and the delete button works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what the model relations are between Track and Pack, but it appears the issue is in your link_to.

The second argument should reference the path you want so it'll be something like:

`link_to "Edit", edit_track_path(track)`

If you don't know what the route name is, do a `rake routes` on the command line and see what the corresponding name is for the route you want.

More info here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me on this, I never knew you could pass the object in brackets like that! `track` btw, is simply the object name and is still created as a new `Pack` I tried this again, and for some reason, it says no matching routes, yet when I edit the pack in its show view, it is the same domain path and it works.

Comment: hmm what do you get when you run `rake routes`? And do you have an edit template in your views directory for that controller?

Comment: I get: `packs#index, packs#create, packs#new, packs#edit, packs#show, packs#update, packs#update, packs#destroy` for the packs, the `track` I am referring to in the question is being rendered in a view called `tracksIndie` and it's path is `packs#tracksIndie tracksIndie GET    /indie-soundtracks(.:format)` As for the edit template, I have one in the directory and in the controller. The item will edit fine when done through the products show page, just not when through the view I created for it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "edit the pack in its show view" in the first comment? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue, what is the expected outcome you're looking for and what is the error you're seeing? It sounds like you have the routing and controller action & template in place so it might just be wiring it up correctly.

Comment: Oh, I have a "packs" directory (the MVC) and in that there is the typical edit, new, index, and show. I have a "secondary index" if you will for tracks, in this case, it's called `tracksIndie.html.erb` The show renders each individual pack on its own page, and I am trying to go directly to the edit view of the `(track)` from the view `tracksIndie.html.erb` instead of the MVC's show view.

Comment: Okay, I see. Does `@packs['track-indie']` return an array of Pack? I'd confirm the object is the class that you're expecting. And are you able to go to /packs/:id/edit page and see the edit form? If so then it's a matter of routing the link_to correctly, otherwise it means routing needs to be changed

Comment: Yes, `@packs['track-indie']` returns all items in the `packs` table that have a `:category_id` of `track-indie`. Navigating to /packs/:id/edit does work and I am able to edit the pack.

Comment: Gotcha so it must be an issue with the data being passed into the `link_to "edit'...`. I'd confirm the route name is correct (i.e. edit_track_path) and then confirm that the track has the id attribute loaded. When you call edit_pack_path(track) it's basically a short hand for edit_pack_path(id: track.id) so maybe it's missing the id. Try the explicit path with the id and see if it resolves your problem. If not, I'd be happy to hop on a chat with you to debug this

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was, I changed it from `track` to `edit_pack_path(track)` without removing `method: :edit`. After removing it, the edit page opened and successfully changed the item.